# Gnome shell messes up file selection and Chrome system title bar

Tags: 12.04, gnome, google-chrome

Everything went alright up until a couple of days ago when I connected my Asus U36SD laptop running 12.04 with Gnome Shell to a projector.

In certain cases, currently only affecting a maximized Chrome window and mouse file selection, the regular system title bar and colors get changed to plain white. This does not, however, affect any other browser or window. To make it easier to understand, I attached three screenshots picturing the isssue.

Do you have any idea what could be causing this? There were no upgrades, installs or tweaks done in the past week, so I'm completely in the blue.

[image: chrome unmaximized]

*Unmaximized Chrome window using system title bars. Everything looks alright*

[image: chrome maximized]

*Maximized Chrome window (same settings). System title bar turns blank*

[image: file selection]

*File selection. What should've been a transparent blue-ish area turns white. Selecting individual files still works properly*

Answer (score 1):

This may have to do with the video card driver. I used to have issues like this with an Intel based video card (a Thinkpad laptop). It could only do compiz/fancy 3D desktop stuff on one of the "pipes" in that card, and so the display on the laptop had to be completely turned off in order for stuff to work properly on the projector/secondary display.

If I were you, I'd try that - to connect a monitor/projector and see if it behaves differently if you disable the physically attached/mounted laptop screen and only use the monitor/project. If the problem goes away, I'd report all of this as a bug against the video card driver on Launchpad.

Comment: the issue is still there, even if I reconnect to another monitor/projector. The strange thing is that it doesn't affect the entire system (as I wrote in the question, this only goes for Google Chrome and the selection area). I even tried reinstalling Chrome, but with no result.

Comment: it's definitely a driver problem. Try to change the theme colors (other than ambiance). or try to install compiz effects

Comment: you can also try to install Chromium browser to check if it shares the same problem

Comment: give another try to chrome themes http://www.chrometheme.net/